# One-to-Many and One-to-One (from Customer to Address)

Tags: entity-framework-core

I try to create two relationships between two entities in EF Core.

- One-to-One: *Customer.DefaultAddress -> Address*
- One-to-Many: *Customer.Addresses -> Address*

You can see it in my code:

```cs
public class Customer
{
    public Guid CustomerId { get; set; }

    // can be null
    public ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
    
    // can be null
    public Address DefaultAddress { get; set; }
    
    // ...
}

public class Address
{
    public Guid AddressId { get; set; }
    
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public Guid CustomerId { get; set; }

    // ...
}

public class Context : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    { 
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Server=.;Database=AllAndDefault;Trusted_Connection=True;");
    }
}
```

When I try to create a migration, it throws an exception:

> Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation property 'Address.Customer' of type 'Customer'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'Entity
> TypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

I tried to configure the relationship manually in the OnModelCreating method, but it still does not work with other exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be explicit about how the relationship is defined as EF can't infer the correct mapping.

```cs
public class Customer {
    public Guid CustomerId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
    public Address DefaultAddress { get; set; }
    //foreign-key for the one-to-one relationship
    public Guid? DefaultAddressId { get; set; }
}
public class Address {
    public Guid AddressId { get; set; }
    public Guid CustomerId { get; set; }
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
}

public class Context : DbContext {
    //...
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
           .HasMany(a => a.Addresses)
           .WithOne(c => c.Customer)
           .HasForeignKey(c => c.CustomerId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
         .HasOne(a => a.DefaultAddress)
         .WithOne()
         .HasForeignKey<Customer>(e => e.DefaultAddressId);
    }
}
```